# display the searched data in labels of the form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've made a form for searching the bill number. When the bill is found in database table, the data should be shown in labels. How can I do that? Then the user press the button to pay for the billed amount.

view block

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{action('OrderedBookController@billPay')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="row" style="padding-left: 1%;">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Bill Number</label><span class="required">*</span>
                                <input type="text" maxlength="15" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off" name="NBillNumber" class="form-control"/>                                
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group"></div> 
                            <div class="form-group" style="padding-left: 5%;">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>        
                            </div> 
                        </div>                      
                </div>
</form>

<div class="row" style="padding-left: 1%;">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Book ID</label>
                <output name="NBookID" class="form-control" aria-readonly="true"/> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Billed Date</label>
                    <output name="NBilledDate" class="form-control" aria-readonly="true"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 3%;">
            <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Billed Number</label>
                    <output name="NBilledNumber" class="form-control" aria-readonly="true"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Quantity</label>
                <output name="NBilledQuantity" class="form-control" aria-readonly="true"/>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"style="padding-left: 3%;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Price</label>
                <output name="NBilledPrice" class="form-control" aria-readonly="true"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Remarks</label>
                <output name="NBilledRemarks" class="form-control" aria-readonly="true"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">PAY</button>        
            </div> 
        </div>
</div>
```

OrderedBookController code block

```
public function searchBill()
    {
        return view ( 'pages.payBill');
    }

public function billPay(Request $request)
    {
        $billNum = $request->input('NBillNumber');

        if($billNum != ""){
            $billsrch = OrderedBook::where ( 'BilledNum', $billNum )->get ();
            if (count ( $billsrch ) > 0)
            {
                return response()->json($billsrch);
                return view('pages.payBill', compact('billsrch'));
            }                
            else
            {
                return view ( 'pages.payBill',compact('billsrch'))->with('alert-danger', 'Sorry No details found');
            }

        }
    }
```

While debugging my `billPay` method, I am getting data from the database. Then how to show data in my view block. In previous forms I am displaying the data in a table, but now I need to show my data in form and update the paid column on button press `PAY`. How can I do this?

route code block

```
Route::get('/billSearch','OrderedBookController@searchBill');
Route::post('/billPay','OrderedBookController@billPay');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to display your html based on conditions like this.
if your form is post method you should process through ajax. 
if your form is get method just put condition like this.

```
@if ($billsrch)
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{action('OrderedBookController@billPay')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="row" style="padding-left: 1%;">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Bill Number</label><span class="required">*</span>
                                <input type="text" maxlength="15" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off" name="NBillNumber" class="form-control"/>                                
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group"></div> 
                            <div class="form-group" style="padding-left: 5%;">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>        
                            </div> 
                        </div>                      
                </div>
</form>

<div class="row" style="padding-left: 1%;">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Book ID</label>
                <output name="NBookID" class="form-control" aria-readonly="true"/> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Billed Date</label>
                    <output name="NBilledDate" class="form-control" aria-readonly="true"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 3%;">
            <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Billed Number</label>
                    <output name="NBilledNumber" class="form-control" aria-readonly="true"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Quantity</label>
                <output name="NBilledQuantity" class="form-control" aria-readonly="true"/>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"style="padding-left: 3%;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Price</label>
                <output name="NBilledPrice" class="form-control" aria-readonly="true"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Remarks</label>
                <output name="NBilledRemarks" class="form-control" aria-readonly="true"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">PAY</button>        
            </div> 
        </div>
</div>
@endif
```